# C malloc, realloc. How to remove single element from array.

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, realloc

I've got a homework to create 2 functions **add** which adds element to dynamic array (what i've done) and **remove** which removes indicated element from that array. I have a problem with that 2nd function. I have no clue how to code it. 
PS. I can't use memmove().

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int *tab, int n);
void add(int x, int y, int *tab, int idx);
void remove_element(int *tab, int idx, int array_length);


int main() {
        int *tab = malloc(24*sizeof(*tab));
        int  idx = 0;

        tab[idx++] = 44;
        tab[idx++] = 82;
        tab[idx++] = 57;
        tab[idx++] = 77;

        printf("Before insert\n");
        print_array(tab, idx);

        idx++;
        add(7, 0, tab, idx);

        printf("After insert\n");
        print_array(tab, idx);
        free(tab);

        idx--;
        printf("After delete\n");
        remove_element(tab, 3, idx);

        print_array(tab, idx);
        free(tab);
    return(0);
}

void print_array(int *tab, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("t[%d] = %d\n", i, tab[i]);
    }
}

void add(int x, int y, int *tab, int idx) {
        int i;
        for (i = idx; i > y; i--) {
            tab[i] = tab[i-1];
        }
        tab[y] = x;
}


void remove_element(int *tab, int idx, int array_length) {
    void *tmp = realloc(tab, (array_length - 1) * sizeof(int) );
    array_length = array_length - 1;
    tab = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Any good book or tutorial or teacher should have told you that arguments in C are passed *by value*. That means they are *copied*, and the function only have the copy. Modifying a copy will *not* modify the original. Now think about that in relation to your `remove_element` function, and do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Just a comment. The add function doesn't create new memory, but the remove function does decrement the memory. It does not look a robust design

Answer (score 0):

About your array you can keep information about its size (eg `iSize`) and the number of elements in use (eg `iUse`). `iUse<=isize`, of course.

When you need to add an element but the array is too small (`iUse==iSize`), you increase its size, add the element and increment `iUse`.

When you remove an element, you just decrement `iUse` and, if you can't use `memmov`, make a loop to move al higher elements down.

Comment: How can I get a size of dynamic array? I tried sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]). I found out that it returns size of pointer instead of size of array.

Comment: @Aza: You can't get the size of dynamically allocated memory. You need to explicitly keep the track of the allocated size.

Comment: I said _you can keep information about..._ which means you keep track of it yourself when you allocate and reallocate. For example your first allocation in main is 24 ints.